# Display only days on scaleTime ticks

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to remove the month and year ticks from the x axis of a scaleTime, but don't know if it's possible:

[image: xAxis of scaleTime]

I've tried to use the tickFormat method but I cannot access the month and year values. I only get the expected results by changing the scale to a linearScale and formatting manually the values.

It is possible to get the expected result with a time scale?

```js
const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20 };
const width = 1000 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
const height = 100 - margin.left - margin.right;
const totalWidth = width + margin.top + margin.bottom;
const totalHeight = height + margin.left + margin.right;

let svg = d3.select('.chart')
  .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight)
  .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

let xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .rangeRound([0, width])
  .domain([
    new Date(1482883200000), // 2016-12-28
    new Date(1485993600000) // 2017-02-02
  ]);

let xAxis = d3
  .axisBottom(xScale);

svg.call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it's hard to know **how** the axis generator is going to display the ticks for a time scale, I suggest that you filter the ticks after they were created:

```
d3.selectAll(".tick").each(function(d) {
    if (d3.timeFormat("%Y")(d) == d3.select(this).text() ||
        d3.timeFormat("%B")(d) == d3.select(this).text()) {
        d3.select(this).remove();
    }
})
```

Here is the demo:

```js
const totalWidth = 800;
const totalHeight = 100;

let svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

let xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .rangeRound([20, totalWidth - 20])
    .domain([
        new Date(1482883200000), // 2016-12-28
        new Date(1485993600000) // 2017-02-02
    ]);

let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,40)").call(xAxis);

var format = d3.timeFormat("%a %d");

d3.selectAll(".tick").each(function(d) {
    if (d3.timeFormat("%Y")(d) == d3.select(this).text() || d3.timeFormat("%B")(d) == d3.select(this).text()) {
        d3.select(this).remove();
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply format the date on the x axis using `tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%d"))`

```
let xAxis = d3
   .axisBottom(xScale)
   .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%d"))
```